# Runtime for a collision-detection algorithm

Tags: algorithm, collision-detection, particles

I've come up with an algorithm for predicting the collision between two particles. Given a rectangular environment (width *`w`*, height *`h`*), and two particles with known starting positions and velocities, it can determine

- Whether or not the two particles will *ever* collide
- If so, the time at which the two particles will next collide

in a finite number of steps, so to say `O(1)`. By extension, it can do this for *n* particles in `O(n^2)`. Is there anything novel in this approach?

I'm assuming that the particles move in a linearly and at a constant velocity, and occupy points (so a collision would be when two particles occupy the same point).

Thank you for helping.

Comment: I think it does need O(n(n+1)) which is O(n^2), to check all pairs of particles. I don't think there is a faster algorithm.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "novel". It seems like a straightforward enough problem that you'd be unlikely to become rich and famous from it. But it's also not a problem that I've seen posed in the past.

Comment: (That's assuming that particles bounce off the edges of the environment. If they don't, then of course this is a trivial problem.)

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy to do this in O(n^2) time for n particles simply by comparing all pairs of particles, and extrapolating a line segment for each to see where they collide.

More efficient algorithms exist, often based around the idea of indexing your objects in memory using something such as a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree); the [Wikipedia article on collision detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection) has a good overview of another possible approach.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

The algorithm I've designed can also run in _n_ dimensions (predicting collision between two particles) in O(n) (exact number of cases to check is 4(n-1) ). It can _prove_ that two particles either will collide at some time _t_, or will never collide at all. Is this any different from the existing approaches?

Comment: @vincemathic You can still do that simply by taking each pair of particles and projecting their paths out to find where their vectors intersect, which is an O(1) operation. I don't know if this can be done in less than O(n^2) time, but it's not remarkable that you can do n^2 O(1) operations in O(n^2) time!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straight-forward solution assuming a rasterized setup and that collisions (inter-particle or particle-wall) do not modify the direction and speed of particles. The main idea is to "paint" the trajectories of the particles into a raster of size `w x h`.

```
allocate a raster of size w*h, each pixel being able to keep a list of (time,particle_id) tuples
for each particle pa
    for each pixel pi on the direction of pa
        store the tuple (time_of_pa_at_pi, pa_id) in the list of pi
for each pixel pi in the raster
    check for collisions inside the list of pi by ordering the tuples by time
```

The worst case scenario is pretty hard to describe, but an upper bound on the performance is `O(n*max(w,h)) + O(wh) + max(w,h)*O(n*logn)`. The worst case scenario(s) probably occurs when all particles (or a large percentage of them) are traveling the same direction. This is extremely unlikely assuming a distribution uniformly at random of all the input params. Assuming that, in the average case scenario, the performance should be a lot better.

Additionally (but this is probably the important part of this answer), you can obtain a speed up if you first allocate a smaller raster (e.g. of size `w/c x h/c`) and you run a probable-collision check in the same manner as above. The pixels in this raster are larger, so the probable-collision step takes less. At the end of this step you get a feeling of what can happen in each macroscopic pixel and then continue your investigation locally (in a recursive way or using some other technique). The `c` above could be a constant or some function of `w`, `h` and `n` (e.g. `c=sqrt(max(w,h))`).

Of course, all the above are useless if `w` and/or `h` are inconveniently large.

Comment: to the down-voter, what part of my answer didn't you like/consider "unreasonable"?